# partially touched code coverage area VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-coverage, xunit

I am doing testing and have to reach certain level of code coverage. I have a problem in the statment of event invocation, the code coverage is always showing partially touched case, therefore, affecting my overall coverage.

**How can I make it to count as full coverage**

I have seen some questions for the same but none has the exact answer to solve such small thing (or atleast small looking thing).

The code is given below

```
public class ClassToBeTested
{
    public event Action myEvent = delegate {};

    public void Function1 ()
    {
        myEvent?.invoke();  //partially touched
    }
}


public class  TestingClass
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestingFunction1()
    {
        bool eventCheck = false;
        ClassToBeTested obj = new ClassToBeTested();
        obj.myEvent += delegate { eventCheck = true ;};
        obj.Function1();
        Assert.True(eventCheck);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're assigning the event to a new delegate, but as far as I can see, nothing is ever calling the Function which invokes the event?  Am I missing something or do you simply need a `ClassTobeTested.Function1();` call in your unit test before the `Assert` line?

Comment: I edited my question. So should I not assign it to anything or how I do it?

Comment: Something about the syntax of that example does not look accurate.

Comment: I edited it, I just wrote the example of how things are working and what is the problem, its not the real code.

Comment: While not the real code, the provided example wont even compile as delegate `Action<T>` does not take 0 arguments.. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi Could you please try now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it coded with the null check makes it impossible to get higher coverage because *`myEvent` can never be null* because you've initialized it to non-null:

```
public event Action myEvent = delegate {};
```

To get full coverage you need:

```
public event Action myEvent = delegate {};

public void Function1 ()
{
    myEvent.invoke();
}
```

or

```
public event Action myEvent;

public void Function1 ()
{
    myEvent?.invoke();
}
```

With two tests: one that tests when `myEvent` is null, and one where you've added an event handler.